# Syntax error on if statement in unix shell scripting: ksh: test: argument expected"

Tags: shell, if-statement, unix, ssh, sunos

Error on executing if statement in ssh command in unix shell scripting.
Linux and sunos

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh u1@s1 "if [ $a == 100 ] 
then
echo Hey that is a large number
pwd
fi
date"
```

Error:
Ksh: test: argument expected

Comment: You need a `;` before the `then`, and another one before the `fi`, if this really is on one line the way it shows when viewing the question.

Comment: (if it's _not_, use a line with three backticks and nothing else to start and end literal code segments)

Comment: also, is the _one_ backtick around the `ssh` command really part of your code? You shouldn't have that at all: it makes your local shell try to interpret the output of `ssh` itself as code.

Comment: It's also suboptimal to use `==` in `[` -- for best portability, you should use the only POSIX-standardized string comparison operator, which is `=`.

Comment: Is `$a` something that's supposed to be defined locally or remotely? Your command given above is expanding it locally, *before* `ssh` is run. Note, you also need a `;` or a newline after the `fi` before the `date`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get this if `$a` is empty:

```sh
$ unset a
$ [ $a == 100 ] && echo one hundred || echo not
ksh: [: argument expected
not
```

Solution: quote the variable

```sh
$ [ "$a" == 100 ] && echo one hundred || echo not
not
```

Or use the double bracket conditional

```sh
$ [[ $a == 100 ]] && echo one hundred || echo not
not
```

I'm using ksh 93u+

Comment: And when use single brackets should be `-eq`, not `==`

Comment: Double brackets as well